# Anonymous user can´t see views button which is added in template

Tags: views, theming

I want to have back button in views page..

The button is added at the bottom of this code.. As Administrator I can see it normally.. But when I log out, it´s gone.. Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Are you caching pages for Anonymous users? Flush the cache.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://cdn.inmotionhosting.com/support/images/stories/edu/Drupal_7/Configuration/Development/Performance/config-deve-perf-cache-anon.png

Comment: yeah im caching for AU.. still doesnt work, but thank you for your answer ;) anything else ?

Comment: yeah. that is what I meant.

Comment: still nothing ..

Comment: I also triet to do it via php views.. I added global php field and put there code of button.. it worked.. but only for admin.